# Get items that are closed within 1 business day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL database table of tickets that I need to count where the ticket has been closed within 1 business day of it being opened.

I've been able to get some of the way with my query below, but I'm at a loss in how to allow that to work by business days. So tickets opened on a Friday can be completed on a Monday and still count as being closed within one business day.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM helpdesk 
WHERE hd_closeDateTime < hd_openDateTime + interval 1 day  
AND hd_status = 2
```

I think I need some sort of `DAYOFWEEK(timestamp_column) BETWEEN 2 AND 6`? But I'm not sure how this fits with my current WHERE part.

The pertinent parts of the table are below:

```
CREATE TABLE `helpdesk` (
 `hd_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `hd_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `hd_openDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `hd_closeDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `hd_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Thanks to @Akina this is what is now working. The ELT looks up the number of days to add to the ticket using the + Interval function so it adds 3 days on Friday, 3 days on Saturday, and 2 days on Sunday allowing the tickets to be counted if they are completed within a business day.

```
SELECT *, DAYOFWEEK(hd_openDateTime)
FROM helpdesk 
WHERE hd_closeDateTime < hd_openDateTime + INTERVAL 
ELT(DAYOFWEEK(hd_openDateTime),2,1,1,1,1,3,3) DAY  
AND hd_status = 2
```

For anyone interested in more info

ELT - https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-elt-function.php

DAYOFWEEK - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_dayofweek.asp

Comment: So only if the ticket was opened on a Friday, you would need to add two more days to your interval ...

Comment: Provide data sample (textual code-formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 5-7 rows) and desired output for this data with explanations.

Comment: @CBroe that's right. If the ticket is opened on monday at 1100 and completed tuesday before 1100 that should return 1. If the ticket is opened friday at 1100 and completed before monday 1100 that should also return 1.

I think that makes sense

Comment: What if the ticket is opened on monday at 11:00 and completed tuesday at 12:00? 0 or 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test, for example, this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM helpdesk 
WHERE hd_closeDateTime < DATE(hd_openDateTime) + INTERVAL ELT(DAYOFWEEK(hd_openDateTime),3,2,2,2,2,2,4) DAY  
  AND hd_status = 2
```

Only date (not time) is taken into account. If the time must be taken into account too then

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM helpdesk 
WHERE hd_closeDateTime < hd_openDateTime + INTERVAL ELT(DAYOFWEEK(hd_openDateTime),2,1,1,1,1,1,3) DAY  
  AND hd_status = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, so I've amended slightly for the Friday issue and added the ELT for Friday to 3 to allow that to fall into the Monday.

Comment: @MatthewBarraud This is a pattern, you'd adjust it to your need.

Comment: Thanks, have amended my original post with you answer and learnt about ELT, really useful